# Class name is an allowed class to load

Tags: java, security, reflection

I am using java.
I have a String with a class name which the code tries to load using reflection.
I would like to check if the class is of a specific type which I allow and not some other class. How can I do it without loading the class first. I am afraid it is a malicious class.

Comment: Do you control your classpath? If you do, then they can only load classes you allow. For example, create a new `ClassLoader` and have it only contain "safe" classes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes

Comment: Why would you have malicious classes in your classpath if you control it??